# How to match the last occurance of a word before matching the rest of the expression

Tags: mysql, regex

In this example string:

`select 07142 from jira98 union all select cast(100 as decimal(5,0)) as JIRKEY, ID, SEQCE, pnme, DESCTION, ICURL, STATOR FROM  jira100.prity union all select * from jira92 union all`

I would like to this match only this part using regex:

`select cast(100 as decimal(5,0)) as JIRKEY, ID, SEQCE, pnme, DESCTION, ICURL, STATOR FROM  jira100.prity union all`

I have the following regex but it matches from the first select.
I would like the regex to match the Last 'select' before the rest of my regex.

```
((select).+?(FROM)\s+(jira100).+?(union)\s+(all)\s)
```

Thanks

Comment: Welcome, how are you using the pattern, what tool/lang? To get the last match you can in many cases just let a greedy [`.*` consume before](https://regex101.com/r/8Wg9Je/1). Depends on task.

Comment: My SQL, to give more context I have more then 100 select statements unioned, and i'd just like to match only the select statement which pulls from jira100. (regardless of the table name and while including union all)

Comment: In the example you gave me if I can get Group2 + the rest of the match that would work. 
Without this part in the beggining:  select select 07142 from jira98 union all

Comment: What distinguishes that `SELECT` from the others?

Answer (score -1):

If you use MySQL 8+ this code will be work.

(select.+?) (select.+) (select.+)

Use $2(\2) with subpattern

[regexp101](https://regex101.com/r/ftj3B6/1)